# Microsoft graph API to send Email using token authentication using client secret . I have pasted token in https://jwt.ms/ but missing scope

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using Graph API to send emails and using clientID, Secret and APPID. I'm getting the token, but I'm unable to send emails:

> Code: NoPermissionsInAccessToken Message: The token contains no
> permissions, or permissions can not be understood. Inner error:
> AdditionalData: requestId: 53f1cddb-4f38-4efa-ab62-624b495374f0 date:
> 2020-12-02T10:46:42 ClientRequestId:
> 53f1cddb-4f38-4efa-ab62-624b495374f0

I have added API permission as delegated to `mail.send`

```
IPublicClientApplication publicclientapplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                     .Create(clientId)
                     .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                     .Build();
             
           UsernamePasswordProvider authprovider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicclientapplication,scopes);

            var authResult = await publicclientapplication
                    .AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, username, passwordstring(stringpassword))
                    .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return authResult.AccessToken;
```

Code that I'm using to send is:

```
await graphServiceClient.Me .SendMail(email, false) .Request() .PostAsync();
```

Comment: Have you validated your token using https://jwt.ms and see if it contains the correct permission/scopes in it?

Comment: yes validated the token but not able to see scopes in the content

Comment: How do we provide admin consent to application permission for API permission for mail.send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that delegated permission is for app+user authentication while application permission is for app-only authentication.

You should have used a wrong Microsoft Graph authentication provider or you have added a wrong type of permission.

Now you should be using [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider), which uses client credential flow and application permission. But you didn't add **application permission** in your Azure AD app. It's why you get the error `The token contains no permissions`. If your application doesn't require a user to sign in, you could use this client credentials provider. But you need to add **application permission** instead of delegated permission into AAD app and remember to use `graphServiceClient.Users["{id or userPrincipalName}"].SendMail` to send the mail.

For delegated permission and `graphServiceClient.Me` endpoint, you should choose [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#AuthCodeProvider) which requires you to implement sign-in interactively. Keep using delegated permission and `graphServiceClient.Me.SendMail`.

If you don't want to sign in interactively but want to have a user in the access token, you need to choose [Username/password provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#UsernamePasswordProvider). But it's not recommended by Microsoft. See **Warning** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). Keep using delegated permission and `graphServiceClient.Me.SendMail` as well.

**UPDATE：**

A sample with Username/password provider:

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();

UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var email = "Your Username Here";
var str = "Your Password Here";
var password = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in str) password.AppendChar(c);

//prepare message and saveToSentItems here

await graphClient.Me
.SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
.Request()
.PostAsync();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Add application permission `Mail.Send` into Azure AD app.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

//prepare message and saveToSentItems here

await graphClient.Users["{id or userPrincipalName}"]
    .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225469/discussion-on-answer-by-allen-wu-microsoft-graph-api-to-send-email-using-token-a).